# Flask Custom Validation Error - TypeError: Unsupported type "<class 'wtforms.fields.core.UnboundField'>"

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to add a custom validation method in Flask WTF but it keeps failing.

So the my goal is to check is the value exists in a dynamodb table when validating the form.

not sure what i am missinf

```
def pipeline_exists(self, pipeline_name):
    ses = boto3.session.Session()
    try:
        dynamodb = ses.resource('dynamodb')
    except Exception as exception:
        message = 'Error on DynamoDB client'
        logging.error("Dynamodb client session failed: %d %s", exception)
        msg = " Dynamodb client session failed: " + str(exception)

        raise exception
    table_name = 'my_tbl'
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('pipeline_name').eq(pipeline_name)
    )

    print(response)
    if response['count'] > 0:
        raise validators.ValidationError('Pipeline ' + pipeline_name.data + ' already exists')
    else:
        True
```

And Form is

```
class AddPipeline(Form):
    pipeline_name = StringField('Pipeline Name', [validators.Length(min=10, max=250), pipeline_exists])
```

The error i get is:

```
TypeError: Unsupported type "<class 'wtforms.fields.core.UnboundField'>" for value "<UnboundField(StringField, (), {})>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer:
i was missing the .data option in the key lookup

```
def pipeline_exists(self, pipeline_name):
    ses = boto3.session.Session()
    try:
        dynamodb = ses.resource('dynamodb')
    except Exception as exception:
        message = 'Error on DynamoDB client'
        logging.error("Dynamodb client session failed: %d %s", exception)
        msg = " Dynamodb client session failed: " + str(exception)

        raise exception
    table_name = 'my_tbl'
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('pipeline_name').eq(pipeline_name.data)
    )

    print(response)
    if response['count'] > 0:
        raise validators.ValidationError('Pipeline ' + pipeline_name.data + ' already exists')
    else:
        True
```